# what are the fullforms of the different options during git add -up

Tags: git, version-control

Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]?

I just y - yes, n - no, and q - quit
what are the others?

can I reset a specific hunk (working directory) to the last committed version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
       y : stage this hunk
       n : do not stage this hunk
       q : quit; do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
       a : stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
       d : do not stage this hunk nor any of the later hunks in the file
       g : select a hunk to go to
       / : search for a hunk matching the given regex
       j : leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
       J : leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
       k : leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
       K : leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
       s : split the current hunk into smaller hunks
       e : manually edit the current hunk
       ? : print help
```

You can always go with ? for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` to get the meanings for all the symbols.

You can reset a specific hunk to last committed version using `git checkout -p`

Just an FYI, `git reset` takes a `-p` too in case you want to unstage hunk by hunk.